# How to store a Hashmap(Integer keys, hashmap values) in a txt file in java?

Tags: java, file, hashmap, save

I want to store the meteosemana hashmap(meteoSemana has integer keys and a hashmap has values) in a txt file... but  the compiler just jumps to the end of the method and nothing is stored.

```
public void storeEmpresa(String f) 
{
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(this.meteoSemana);

        oos.writeObject(this.mapaUAV);
        oos.writeObject(this.mapaArmazem);
        oos.writeObject(Servicos.cod);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("Ficheiro guardado com sucesso \n");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {System.out.println("Falha na gravação do ficheiro! Tem permissões de administrador?");System.exit(0);}
    catch(IOException e)
    { System.out.println("Falha na gravação de ficheiro!"); System.exit(0);} 
}


public void loadEmpresa(String f) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        this.meteoSemana = (HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,meteoPeriodo>>)ois.readObject();

        this.mapaUAV = (HashMap<Integer,UAV>)ois.readObject();
        this.mapaArmazem = (HashMap<Integer,Armazem>)ois.readObject();
        Servicos.cod = (Integer)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {} 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {}
}
```

Comment: `jumps to the end of the method`: Do you mean it catches an exception?

Comment: @jhamon, yes jumps to catch(IOException e)

Comment: and the exception says... ?

Comment: What is the type of meteoPeriodo? --> Does it have implements Serializable ?

Comment: @jamp, it says "Failed to store in the file!"

Comment: that is what you write... what is the message of the exception? e.printStackTrace()

Comment: @Andie2302, it's an object

Comment: meteoPeriodo should be a class or interface, not an object

Comment: @jamp, sorry it's a class

Comment: is it serializable? and what about the exception?

Comment: @jamp, yes I forgot to implement serializable in the class meteoPeriodo. problem solved. thanks for your tip